# Empty response body after return ResponseEntity error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have method in my rest controller

```
  @PostMapping("/access")
  public ResponseEntity<?> login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequestDto loginRequestDto) {
    try {
      return ResponseEntity.ok(authService.login(loginRequestDto));
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      return ResponseEntity.status(401).body(exception.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

When my method throw error, this method return response with status 401 but without response message (in dev tools blank screen in response body). When I logged this response, response body is Readable stream.

I go through same questions but any answer didnt help me.

For example I have in my application yml

```
 error:
      include-message: always
      include-binding-errors: always
```

I also tried to return any valid object in response body because I thought problem in return single String but no, when I return object, in dev tools I have blank response body.
Also when I return 200 or any other successful status with object, I receive it in devtols response body

Comment: to gain control over a (spring-security) 401 response, we need/used an "AuthenticationEntryPoint" ... [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74584549/592355), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74545265/592355), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54932011/592355)

Comment: But I have no response body even if return 404, any error

Answer (score 0):

The 401 Unauth error is being thrown before this piece of code is hit. You need to set up a custom error handler that has a defined method for this response.

https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api

[ResponseEntityExceptionHandler returns empty response body for 401 exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932011/responseentityexceptionhandler-returns-empty-response-body-for-401-exceptions)

Comment: But I have no response body even if return 404, any error